# Choose the correct one(s). Differentiability of complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Choose the correct one(s).

1. $f(z)=|z|$ is differentiable exactly at origin.
2. $f(z)=|z|^2$ is differentiable exactly at origin.
3. $f(z)=z|z|$ is differentiable exactly at origin.
4. $f(z)=z Re(z)$ is differentiable exactly at origin.

**My attempt**

1. I could prove that $f(z) $ is not differentiable at $z=0.$ I am not able to prove the differentiability of $f(z)$ for $z\neq 0$
   $\lim _{h\to 0\ }\frac{f\left(z+h\right)-f\left(z\right)}{h}=\lim _{h\to 0\ }\frac{\sqrt{(z+h)\overline{(z+h)}}-\sqrt{(z)\overline{z}}}{h}$

I am stucked here.

2. I could prove that $f(z) $ is  differentiable at $z=0.$ To to prove the differentiability of $f(z)$ for $z\neq 0. $ Consider
   $\lim _{h\to 0\ }\frac{f\left(z+h\right)-f\left(z\right)}{h}=\lim _{h\to 0\ }\frac{(z+h)\overline{(z+h)-(z)\overline{z}}}{h}=\lim _{h\to 0\ }\frac{z\overline z+h\overline{z}+z\overline{h}+h\overline{h}-z\overline{z}}{h}=\lim _{h\to 0\ }\frac{h\overline{z}+z\overline{h}+h\overline{h}}{h}.$ Here limit doesnot exists. Since $\lim _{h\to 0\ }\frac{z\overline{h}}{h}$ does not exists.
3. I could prove that $f(z) $ is  differentiable at $z=0.$ To to prove the differentiability of $f(z)$ for $z\neq 0. $ Consider
   $\lim _{h\to 0\ }\frac{f\left(z+h\right)-f\left(z\right)}{h}=\lim _{h\to 0\ }\frac{(z+h) \sqrt{(z+h)\overline{(z+h)}}-z\sqrt{(z)\overline{z}}}{h}$

I am stucked here.

4. I could prove that $f(z) $ is  differentiable at $z=0.$ To to prove the differentiability of $f(z)$ for $z\neq 0. $ Consider
   $\lim _{h\to 0\ }\frac{f\left(z+h\right)-f\left(z\right)}{h}=\lim _{h\to 0\ }\frac{(z+h)Re(z+h)-(z)Re(z)}{h}=\lim _{h\to 0\ }\frac{(z)Re(z)+zRe(h)+hRe(z)+hRe(h)-(z)Re(z)}{h}=\lim _{h\to 0\ }\frac{zRe(h)+hRe(z)+hRe(h)}{h}.$

I am stucked here. I am not able to solve further. May I get help in 1.,3.,4..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $z_0\ne0$, then $z\mapsto|z|$ is not differentiable at $z_0$. To see why, see that$$\lim_{z\to z_0,\ z\in\Bbb R^+z_0}\frac{|z|-|z_0|}{z-z_0}=\lim_{\lambda\to1, \lambda\in\Bbb R^+}\frac{|\lambda z_0|-|z_0|}{\lambda z_0-z_0}=\frac{|z_0|}{z_0}\ne0$$whereas$$\lim_{z\to z_0,\ |z|=|z_0|}\frac{|z|-|z_0|}{z-z_0}=0.$$
2. What you did is fine.
3. Let $f$ be your function. If $f$ was differentiable at a point $z_0$ other than $0$, then the same would be true for $\frac{f(z)}z$. But, we have already seen that that does not happen.
4. The function $\operatorname{Re}$ is differentiable nowhere, because$$\lim_{z\to z_0,\ \operatorname{Re}(z)=\operatorname{Re}(z_0)}\frac{\operatorname{Re}(z)-\operatorname{Re}(z_0)}{z-z_0}=0$$whereas$$\lim_{z\to z_0,\ \operatorname{Im}(z)=\operatorname{Im}(z_0)}\frac{\operatorname{Re}(z)-\operatorname{Re}(z_0)}{z-z_0}=1.$$It's now easy do deduce from this that $z\mapsto z\operatorname{Re}(z)$ is diffferentiable at the origin and only there.

Comment: Sir, Is there any result connecting the differentiability of a complex function and differentiability of its real and complex part?

Comment: Sure: the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations).

Comment: I mean a function $f=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is differentiable at $z=a+ib$. Can we say that $u(x,y), v(x,y)$ differentiable at (a,b)? viz

Comment: Differentiable as functions from $\Bbb R^2$ into $\Bbb R$? Yes, they are.

Comment: what about  from $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$

Comment: Never, unless they are constant.