# Consider the function: $f(x+iy)=\sqrt{|xy|}$. Then

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function: $f(x+iy)=\sqrt{|xy|}$. Then

1. $f$ is continuous at $0.$
2. $f$ satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equation.
3. $f$ is differentiable at $0.$
4. $f $ continuous everywhere.

**My Attempt:-**

1. Let $x=r\cos \theta, y=r \sin\theta $
   $$f(x+iy)=f(r,\theta)=\sqrt{|xy|}=\sqrt{|r\cos \theta \cdot r \sin\theta|}=\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\sin(2\theta)}$$

As $x+iy \to 0+i0$. Then $r \to 0\implies \lim_{(x+iy)\to 0+i0}f(x+iy)=\lim_{r \to 0}f(r, \theta)=0.$
Hence, $f$ is continuous at $(0,0).$

2. Based on comments in [Choose the correct one(s). Differentiability of complex function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917043/choose-the-correct-ones-differentiability-of-complex-function)
   $u(x,y)=\sqrt{|xy|}$ and $v(x,y)=0$

$u_x(0,0)=0, u_y(0,0),v_x(0,0),v_y(0,0)=0, f_y(0,0)=0+i0=if_x(0,0)$ Cauchy Riemann conditin satisfied.

3. Hence, $f$ is differentiable at $z=0$

4.True, since, it is the composition of continuous functions. Hence it is continuous.

Am I correct?

Comment: Sorry, I think you proved that 1 is true, so how can you say that is false in 4?

Comment: Sorry. I will correct it.

Comment: Does it ask if $f$ satisfies the C-R. equations *at $0$* or in general? What, moreover, does it mean to say $f$ is differentiable at $z=0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin perhaps this is a "select all that apply" problem.  Hopefully no one assumed the exercise to prove all of these statements...